# How to find Eigenspaces and Eignenvalues of a Map

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the eigenspaces and eigenvalues of the map $T(y)=t\frac{dy}{dt}$

I know that this means that for eigenvalues $\lambda y=t\frac{dy}{dt}$, so then I integrate and get

$\lambda=\frac{lny}{lnt}$, but I don't think this accomplishes much.  Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: From $\lambda=\frac{\ln y}{\ln t}$, you can solve for $y$, giving $y=t^\lambda$ as the eigenfunctions.

Comment: This is an acceptable answer for the eigenvalues? @BrentKerby

Comment: Well, at first glance, it looks like every number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, since $t^\lambda$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda$, but there could be some issues with $t^\lambda$ not being well-defined (e.g., for complex $\lambda$, or negative $t$); before we could sort that out, though, we would need to know exactly what space of functions $T$ is defined to act on.

Comment: Sometimes I forget to write details!  It's in the space $R[t]_n$, so polynomials in the real numbers up to degree t @BrentKerby

Comment: Good, that will simplify things. So you just need to identify for which values of $\lambda$ the function $t^\lambda$ is in this space of polynomials.

Comment: Well wouldn't this be $\lambda \le n$? @BrentKerby

Comment: Right. To be precise, $\lambda=0,1,2,\dots,n$.

Comment: I didn't know it could be that general the answer, thanks @BrentKerby